# Worklight and dojo: issue with charting into iOs Environment

Tags: ios, charts, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying to implement programmatically a simple pie chart into a mobile application using IBM Worklight and Dojo.

So, i've edited the dojo-build.xml file adding these includes:

```
    <include name="dojox/charting/**"/>
    <include name="dojox/gfx/**"/>
    <include name="dojox/lang/**"/>
    <include name="dojox/color/**"/>
```

and

```
    <include name="dojo/charting-layer.js.compressed.js"/>
```

then into my "createPieChart" javascript function i required these modules:

```
         "dojox/charting/Chart",
         "dojox/charting/plot2d/Pie",
         "dojox/charting/themes/PlotKit/green",
```

And the charting-layer into the worklight init function.
             "dojo/charting-layer",

What happens:

Viewing my application in "common resource" mode from the worklight console, all seems works fine but adding an iOs environment (e.g iPad) a project error occurs, then i'm not able to build my application.

The error is under the folder: 
ipad/native/www/default/dojox/gfx/resources

To build the application i have to remove the gfx module, but in this way i can't use the action2d charting functionality.

I'm doing something wrong or this is a Worklight defect?

My Environment:

Worklight Studio 5.0.5

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Juno Service Release 1
Build id: 20120920-0800

Windows7

Comment: NOTE: I have updated Worklight to the last 5.0.6 release but the error persist

Comment: What is the error exactly? Any message or screenshot that you can share?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. But i think that the error is systematic, if you include the modules described above in your project you can reproduce it.

I'm not able to post a screenshot because Stackoverflow requires at least 10 reputation points. 

The error is the follow:
Into the file "ipad/native/www/default/dojox/gfx/resources/svg2gfx.xsl"

In three points of it (find the string "select="&SupportedElements;" into each xsl:apply-templates tag) the following error occurs: "Xpath is invalid"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue disabling the Eclipse XPath validator. Anyhow looks like a Dojo problem.